# Eclipse cannot resolve classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, runtime

Boy, I'm having difficulties.

The run configuration keeps adding resources to maven, and the resources dont exist.  So, I have to edit the runtime classpath and "Only include the exported items".

Then I get runtime errors that all the classes, starting with String, cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Project properties to look at: `Deployment Assembly` and `Java Build Path`.

Comment: In build path, I have tried jdk 1.7.0.51 and jre 7, same result.

Comment: Did a clean / rebuild, and now get
Error: Could not find or load main class ...

Comment: check your pom.xml.It should have errors .

Comment: I disabled maven nature.  Somehow it started to work again.